# Jquery and dynamic id's

Tags: jquery

I have a Div in a while loop in PHP each with their own id's, according to what id is in MySQL.  With JavaScript i can simply add an onclick event handler to the Div and then call a function.  Now for Jquery, how do i get the Div element for dynamic id's, do ?

```
<?php 
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$id= $row['id'];
echo "<div id='$id' >$id</div>"; 

} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class instead of the id to identify the target. Add a class when you create the elements in PHP, and select on that instead.

```
<?php 
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$id= $row['id'];
echo "<div id='$id' class='someClass' >$id</div>"; 

} ?>
```

Client script:

```
$('.someClass')...
```

Comment: How would I bind a variable to $('.someClass').click without referencing each target element?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all of your dynamically generated `div` tags inside another tag with a known id (let's call it `container` for example).  Then, you can just loop through all of your generated `div` tags like this:

```
$('#container > div').click(function() {
    //your goodies here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("Id*=yourdivid").click(function(){

//use this to access clicked div.
});
```

or if you have some specific class assigned to your div then you can use

```
$(".divclass").click(function(){
//this object will contain the div you clicked.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big php man, but you could prefix some static word before the row id to the div id (example: for row #3, dynamic_3)

```
<?php 
    while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $id= $row['id'];
        echo "<div id='dynamic_$id' >$id</div>"; 
    } ?>
```

Then you can get the divs with jQuery as so:

```
$('div[id^="dynamic_"]')
```

Comment: And if you want to get at the ID in JS again later, $("div").attr("id").split("_")[1];

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could chose to do is let use jquery to create the HTML markup (as opposed to PHP), where you would get a JSON / Array of controls to create, and then do something like:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
$(div).html("My new Div")
    .click(function(){
//PUT your custom scripts here    
});

div.appendTo("#mainDiv");
```

now you can add that div to any container you want.